# Ensuring a widget has a container?

Tags: c++, user-interface

Here is my problem:

In the game gui I'm developing, the "desktop" is a class I call WidgetManager. In order for me to communicate certain things, like focus, between the gui and a widget, every widget must have a pointer to the widget manager. The problem is, the user can add children to a widget which is not yet part of a widget manager. This is where my hacky solution comes in:

```
AguiWidgetManager* AguiWidget::getWidgetManager() const
{

    if(_container)
    return _container;

    if(getTopWidget())
    {
        if(getTopWidget()->getWidgetManager())
        {
            ((AguiWidget*) this)->_container = 
                getTopWidget()->getWidgetManager();
            return _container;
        }
    }

    if(getParent())
    {
        if(getParent()->getWidgetManager())
        {
            ((AguiWidget*) this)->_container = 
                getParent()->getWidgetManager();
            return _container;
        }
    }

    return (AguiWidgetManager*)NULL;


}
```

I'm aware as to what extent this is a terrible idea and terrible code, and breaks the point of consting, but I'm just not sure how else to ensure that a widget has a container.

At first I thought of setting the widget manager pointer to that of its parent when it is added, but like I said, its parent might not have one either at the time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every Widget is created by a WidgetManager, you can pass that in during creation.

I think, however, your problem comes from combining the functions of the WidgetManager (perhaps better referred to as WidgetFactory) and the top-level Widget. I can think of two potential solutions to work with, both with pros and cons.

1: Have a WidgetFactory which produces Widgets. In your engine, keep a pointer to the root Widget. This is your desktop, all Widgets to be displayed must be a child of this (the base of the tree).

When rendering your widgets, you need simply call `RootWidget->Render()` and it will render its children and so on, recursively.

Similarly, to work back up the tree from any given Widget, you call `widget->GetParent()` and it gives the parent. Further calls will step up the tree until you reach the root widget, which has no parent (used directly by the engine).

The setup there is relatively simple and easy to work with, but you need to split the widgets and the thing that creates that.

2: If you'd rather have a mobile widget factory that also acts as a base of operations for your widget army, you could give it some of the same properties as a widget. The cleanest way of doing this is to have the WidgetManager derive from the Widget class that looks something like so:

```
class Widget
{
    virtual void Render() { for_each(mChildren, child->Render()); }
    virtual Widget * GetParent(); // Returns pointer to parent
    virtual WidgetType GetType() { return WT_Widget; }

private:
    WidgetList mChildren;
    Widget * mParent;
}

class WidgetManager
    : public Widget
{
    Widget * GetParent() { return NULL; }
    WidgetType GetType() { return WT_Manager; }
}
```

This provides an easy way to handle both. The WidgetManager has its children and render them quite like each Widget, and working back up the tree is very simple since you call `widget->GetParent()` and it works for both.

If GetParent() returns NULL, you can verify you've reached the WidgetManager by calling GetType. If that returns `WT_Widget`, you may have a problem.

**Edit:** You could also have the WidgetManager hold a pointer to a single root widget, which has a flag set to denote it as the top. Then use the ideas in method 1 to handle working up and down the tree of widgets.